# Not able to run any test on Appium 1.4.13.1 for Android on windows

Tags: android, appium

Appium server detects the device but unable to send any commands hence no test is being performed.

My Desired capabilities >>

```
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.13.1"); capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1");  

 capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1/com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1.RootActivity"); 

 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Appium server logs >>

> Checking if an update is available
>
> Update available to new version 1.4.16.1
>
> Downloading File from https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/AppiumForWindows_1_4_16_1.zip
>
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>
> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
>
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
>
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1","appActivity":"com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1/com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.demo1.RootActivity","appium-version":"1.4.13.1","BROWSER_NAME":"","platformVersion":"6.0","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4"}}
>
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
>
> info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : appium-version, BROWSER_NAME
>
> info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 76d81d77-d187-4dd1-99d1-a469dad3e463
>
> info: Starting android appium
>
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
>
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0
>
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>
> warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb.
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: where adb
>
> info: [debug] Using adb from D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
>
> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>
> info: Found device EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4
>
> info: [debug] Setting device id to EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4
>
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4 wait-for-device
>
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "D:\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s EQ5LA6UGPJPNCAT4 shell "echo 'ready'"
>
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>
> error: Logcat capture failed: spawn ENOENT
>
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture

Answer (score 0):

Setting the SDK path in Appium solved the problem. Now tests are running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not passing any device name in capabilities.
   Try adding the device name in capabilities.
2. Add "ANDROID_HOME" environment variable to android sdk path.
3. Check the path of sdk in appium also.